# How to select the first element following the parent of an element in XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Suppose that I currently have this code:

```
<p>
    <greeting>
        <a name="hello">Hello!</a>
    </greeting>
</p>
<ul>
    <p>This paragraph needs to be selected</p>
</ul>
```

Basically, while being in the `<a>` element in the first part, I need to select all the children of the `<ul>` element below. Is there a way to do this in XSLT?

Comment: Strictly speaking, your XML is not well-formed, because it lacks a single root element. Can we assume your sample is just a snippet and the actual XML is well-formed (if not, using XSLT will be troublesome!)

Comment: @TimC, this is correct, it was just a sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you were positioned on the **a** element, then either of the following two expressions would work

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../following-sibling::ul[1]/p" />

<xsl:value-of select="ancestor::p[1]/following-sibling::ul[1]/p" />
```

The first one assumes the **a** is a 'grand-child' in this case, whereas the second will work with the **a** at any level, but assumes the relevant 'ancestor' you want to check is always a **p**.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, looks like it is going to work (just let me test it first). I was messing with the `following-sibling` quite a bit, but apparently did something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you need to know the parent of `<p>` and `<ul>`. Assuming that element is `<x>`, you would select that using the ancestor axis, then append the path to the descendants you want:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::x/ul/*">
```

Or if that's variable you can use a wildcard:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::*[3]/ul/*">
```